# erfi does not return correct value in python 3.4

Tags: python, scipy, python-3.4

I have tried this:

```
import scipy.special as spec

y=spec.erfi(0.9)
print(y)
```

The output is

```
1.37154320157
```

But the actual answer is 1.16308715367 which can be verified [here](http://keisan.casio.com/exec/system/1180573448)

Please could someone help me solve this problem?

Thanks

Comment: I would say look at the definition of erfi in the scipy docs. It's prob a factor

Comment: @skywalker I've already done that, but thanks anyway, I just don't understand what's wrong, the erf function works fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`erfi` is the *imaginary error function*, `-i erf(i z)` [(docs)](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.erfi.html#scipy.special.erfi).  You want [`erfinv`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.erfinv.html#scipy.special.erfinv):

```
>>> z = 0.9
>>> spec.erf(z)
0.79690821242283216
>>> spec.erfinv(z)
1.1630871536766736
>>> spec.erf(spec.erfinv(z))
0.89999999999999991
```